# Prolog predicate issue

Tags: prolog

I'm having an issue with a part of my assignment. I'm supposed to write a predicate "friendly" which is supposed to be true when network member X is said to be friendly if X likes back everyone who likes him/her.

EDIT: In the below example, barry is friendly as the list of people that like barry is kara and barry likes kara back. Kara is NOT the right answer as the list of people that like Kara are Barry, Clark and Oliver BUT Kara only likes back Barry and Clark so Kara is not friendly.

eg of G = [person(kara, [barry, clark]),person(bruce, [clark, oliver]),person(barry, [kara, oliver]),person(clark, [oliver, kara]),person(oliver, [kara])]

What I have so far;

```
friendly(G, X):- 
    member_(person(X, _), G),
    likers(G, X, L),
    likes_all(G, X, L).

% to get the list of members who like X;

likers(G, X, [Y|T]) :-
    likes(G, Y, X),
    select_(Y, G, G2),
    likers(G2, X, T).
likers([], _, []).
likers([], _, _).
likers(_, _, []).

% select is used to remove the person from the list once visited.

select_(X, [person(X, _)|T], T).
select_(X, [H|T], [H|R]) :-
    select_(X, T, R).

% to check whether X likes all the list of people that like X;

likes_all(G, X, [H|T]):-
    likes(G, X, H),
    likes_all(G, X, T).
likes_all(_, _, []).    
likes_all(G, [H|T], X):-
    likes(G, H, X),
    likes_all(G, T, X).
likes_all(_, [],_).

likes(G, X, Y):- 
    member_(person(X, L), G),
    member_(Y, L).

member_(X, [X|_]).
member_(X, [_|T]) :-
    member_(X, T).
```

My issue is it doesn't work properly. See sample output below.

So, I don't know what is wrong and how I'm supposed to do it. We are not allowed to use any built in predicates or control operators, so no !, ;, =, \=, +, etc, only pure prolog.

Any hint on moving forward is appreciated.

Output:

```
[debug]  ?- friendly([person(kara, [barry, clark]),person(bruce, [clark, oliver]),person(barry, [kara, oliver]),person(clark, [oliver, kara]),person(oliver, [kara])], X).
X = kara ;
X = kara ;
X = kara ;
X = kara ;
X = kara ;
X = bruce ;
X = barry ;
X = barry ;
X = clark ;
X = clark ;
X = oliver ;
false.
```

I think my error is somewhere in likers function. Output of "likers":

```
?- likers([person(kara, [barry, clark]), person(bruce, [clark, oliver]), person(barry, [kara, oliver]), person(clark, [oliver, kara]), person(oliver, [kara])], kara, L).
L = [] ;
L = [barry] ;
L = [barry, clark] ;
L = [barry, clark, oliver] ;
L = [barry, oliver] ;
L = [barry, oliver, clark] ;
L = [clark] ;
L = [clark, barry] ;
L = [clark, barry, oliver] ;
L = [clark, oliver] ;
L = [clark, oliver, barry] ;
L = [oliver] ;
L = [oliver, barry] ;
L = [oliver, barry, clark] ;
L = [oliver, clark] ;
L = [oliver, clark, barry] ;
false.
```

In the above, the right answer would be L = [barry, clark, oliver] or one of the combinations. Is there a way to get that in pure prolog ?

Comment: Can you post also more input data to test the program? Also note that the program you posted doesn't work (`likes/3` and `member_/2` does not exist).

Comment: **1)**  What is `G` representing ??  **2)** For what `X` is supposed `friendly(G, X)` to succeed for `G = [person(alice,[bob]),person(bob,[])]` ??

Comment: Sorry, I added the missing code and edited a bit.

Comment: Is it possible you have misunderstood the instructions? The `person/2` clauses should probably be in the database, not passed in a list.

Comment: No, there is no database. Nonetheless, it should work this way as well if the predicates are correct.

Comment: Ok, but it is much easier to use the language like it was meant to be used rather than writing Python or whatever with a Prolog accent. This is a trivial problem that requires a few lines of code in Prolog, not 30+.

Comment: And please post code, not pictures.

Comment: "right answer would be Barry" - but Oliver doesn't like Barry? My computer says Kara.

Comment: @vs2010noob - I agree with Thomas. The answer can't be Barry.

Comment: @vs2010noob - Also there is a database. When you write prolog code you are filling the database with facts that you then query. Prolog is basically an in-memory database query tool.

Comment: Further explained how "Barry" is correct and not "Kara". @TomasBy I understand it's way easier if built-in stuff was allowed but it's not. Only pure prolog is allowed, I don't get it but that's how we are supposed to solve it.

Comment: The database is built-in. The list that follows Barry has Oliver in it also. Maybe you should just post the instructions you were given.

Comment: I did post the same instructions. I think there is a bit of confusion.
X is not friendly if he is liked back by the people he likes. It's the other way around. First, we have to find a list of people that like X (again not the people X likes) and then check if X likes them back.

Comment: Also, I think I'm going wrong in finding the list of people that like X. I added the output of my "likers" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calming down, and a bit of google, here is an answer that ought to be satisfactory. The key idea is to pass around not only the person `X` we are interested in but also the complement set (`AEX`). Comparing against this is equivalent to negation of comparison with `X`.

```
friendly(X) :-
  G = [person(kara,[barry,clark]),
       person(bruce,[clark,oliver]),
       person(barry,[kara,oliver]),
       person(clark,[oliver,kara]),
       person(oliver,[kara])],
  allppl(G,All),
  mymember(person(X,Xs),G),
  select(X,All,AEX),
  likers(G,X,AEX,[],Fs),
  subset(Fs,Xs).
```

Get a list of all people:

```
allppl([person(P,_)|Rest],[P|Ps]) :-
  allppl(Rest,Ps).
allppl([],[]).
```

This my old `likers/4` plus the complement set.

```
likers([person(Y,Ys)|Rest],X,AEX,Fs0,Fs) :-
  mymember(X,Ys),
  likers(Rest,X,AEX,[Y|Fs0],Fs).
likers([person(_,Ys)|Rest],X,AEX,Fs0,Fs) :-
  subset(Ys,AEX),
  likers(Rest,X,AEX,Fs0,Fs).
likers([],_,_,Fs,Fs).
```

And here are some helper predicates.

```
select(X,[X|Xs],Xs).
select(X,[Y|Xs],[Y|Zs]) :-
  select(X,Xs,Zs).

subset([],_).
subset([X|Xs],Ys) :-
  mymember(X,Ys), subset(Xs,Ys).

mymember(X,[X|_]).
mymember(X,[_|Xs]) :-
  mymember(X,Xs).
```

Now I get

```
?- friendly(X).
X = bruce ? ;
X = barry ? ;
no
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how your program should probably be written:

```
person(kara,[barry, clark]).
person(bruce,[clark,oliver]).
person(barry,[kara,oliver]).
person(clark,[oliver,kara]).
person(oliver,[kara]).

likes_back([],_).
likes_back([Y|Ys],X) :-
    person(Y,Xs),
    member(X,Xs),
    likes_back(Ys,X).

friendly(X) :-
    person(X,Ys),
    likes_back(Ys,X).

?- friendly(X),write(X),nl,fail.
```

When I run it I only get `kara` as a result - which is correct based on my inspection of the data and rules you gave.

Comment: Please see the edit as I explained how Barry is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a solution then, if I understand correctly. I assume that people that nobody likes (Bruce) are not considered friendly.

```
friendly(P) :-
  person_likes(P,Ps),
  findall(X,(person_likes(X,Zs),member(P,Zs)),Fs), Fs \= [],
  check_subset(Fs,Ps).

check_subset([X|Xs],Set) :-
  memberchk(X,Set),
  check_subset(Xs,Set).
check_subset([],_).

person_likes(kara,[barry,clark]).
person_likes(bruce,[clark,oliver]).
person_likes(barry,[kara,oliver]).
person_likes(clark,[oliver,kara]).
person_likes(oliver,[kara]).
```

Result:

```
?- friendly(X).
X = barry ? ;
no
```

If you are not allowed to use `findall/3` then you need to write another three lines of code or so yourself.

Comment: You are right, we are not allowed to use findall. But, how can I write my own findall if we are not allowed any built-in predicates or control structures. I guess that's what I tried to do with my "likers" predicate but it's just not perfect.

Comment: See 2nd answer.

Comment: Also, Bruce is considered to be friendly so we can remove "Fs \= []" from the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could write `likers/4` like this:

```
likers([person(Y,Ys)|Rest],X,Fs0,Fs) :-
  ( memberchk(X,Ys) ->
    Fs1 = [Y|Fs0]
  ; Fs1 = Fs0 ),
  likers(Rest,X,Fs1,Fs).
likers([],_,Fs,Fs).
```

Call it with third parameter empty list.

Addition: without semicolon:

```
likers([person(Y,Ys)|Rest],X,Fs0,Fs) :-
  memberchk(X,Ys),
  likers(Rest,X,[Y|Fs0],Fs).
likers([person(_,Ys)|Rest],X,Fs0,Fs) :-
  \+ memberchk(X,Ys),
  likers(Rest,X,Fs0,Fs).
likers([],_,Fs,Fs).
```

Comment: That includes the disjunction operator which is not allowed for us. There must be another way.

Comment: \+ is also a control operator which is not allowed :(
No control operators are allowed, only pure prolog as mentioned.

Comment: Maybe you could have specified all this BS in the question then.

Comment: I did. I said no built-in stuff. Only pure prolog.

Comment: I have never heard of any "pure prolog" not allowing negation.

Comment: Okay, that's the term our prof used, so I just assumed it was standard. Sorry about that, I mentioned it specifically in the question now.

Comment: I get that but comma is allowed. I know it sucks but that's how our instructions are.

Comment: @vs2010noob - Could you please edit your question to show exactly what you've been asked to do?